# How to bring column header from Top to bottom?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

[Tableau sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S6HU.png)

I basically want to bring the column header(The one with countries name) from top to bottom.
I tried to the analysis -> Layout options -> advanced -> show innermost level at bottom.
I tried looking everywhere and this was the only solution I could find which didn't work for me.
How should I solve this in Tableau ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try swapping `Country` and `Measure Names` pills in the Column shelf and hide Header for Measure Names if necessary.

Or move `Measure Names` pill in the Column to Row shelf.